# Paw - Get last request made using specific environment

Tags: paw-app, web-api-testing

I am trying to use a dynamic field from parsed response. The parsed response must be for the last request made using a specific environment. Is this possible?

Here's the scenario:

```
1. Make Request 1 using Environment A
    Receive Response A1
2. Make Request 1 using Environment B
    Receive Response B1
3. Make Request 2 using environment A, with field from parsed response A1
    Receive Response A2
4. Make Request 2 using environment B, with field from parsed response B1
    Receive Response B2
```

How do I orchestrate steps 3 and 4?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We are planning to implement it properly by using tabs on MacOS Sierra. With each tab operation as dedicated session and you will pin environment selection to a tab.

This is not properly implemented in Paw yet, but you can write a custom Dynamic value for this or use a hacky workaround:

1. Choose a partitioning variable in your environments
   [image: step1]
2. Set a `X-paw-env` header in Request 1 the partitioning environment variable. This way you get the current value of the partitioning variable depending on the environment
   [image: step 2]
3. In Request 2 in the field where you are using the `Response Parsed Body` insert a `Custom` dynamic value instead. Inside there get the latest exchange for Request 1 where the request header matches the value of your partitioning variable for the current environment. Then extract the value you need from the response body using [RegExp Match](https://paw.cloud/extensions/RegExMatch)
   [image: step3]

```js
function evaluate(context){
 var variableValue =  context.getEnvironmentVariableByName("myPartitioningVariable").getCurrentValue()

 var exchanges = context.getRequestByName("Request1").getAllExchanges();
 for (var i = 0; i < exchanges.length; i++) {
  console.log(i, exchanges[i].requestHeaders["X-paw-env"]);
  if (variableValue === exchanges[i].requestHeaders["X-paw-env"]) {
   var dv = new DynamicValue("com.luckymarmot.RegExMatch", { re: '"user":\\s*"([^"]*)', input: exchanges[i].responseBody });
   console.log(exchanges[i].responseBody)
   console.log(i, "returning")
   return dv.getEvaluatedString();
  }
 }

};
```